# How to send username & password when making REST call to a Django web service

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have implemented a REST API using Django rest framework. This is my view:

```
class CustomerList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

I added permission.IsAuthenticated to only allow users with credential (admin/password123) to view the customer list.

I tested and it is working fine on the web browser.

But how do i send the user:password from a client (e.g: android/ios)? I am using 'Advance Rest Client', a chrome extension to test. Where/how should i put my user:password? Header?

I tried this header but it didn't work:

```
Authorization: admin:password123
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. To send user:password via REST query, append it to the query string:

```
example: http://api.example.com/customers

solution: http://username:password123@api.example.com/customers
```